# Installer generator written in Java?

Tags: java, installation, cross-platform

I'm looking for a free cross-platform installer generator that is fully Java-driven (meaning workflow and plugins are written in Java). Ideally the installer should download the JRE on-demand instead of bundling it directly into the installer. Does something like this already exist?

Please note that InstallAnywhere no longer offers a free edition.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- [IzPack](http://izpack.org/)
- [Antigen](http://antigen.sourceforge.net/)
- [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net)
- [Antstaller](http://antinstaller.sourceforge.net)
- [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/introduction.html)
- [Lift Off Java Installer](http://liftoff.sourceforge.net/index.en.html)
- [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)
- [VAInstall](http://vainstall.sourceforge.net/)
- [Packlet](http://packlet.sourceforge.net/)
- [Mini Installer](http://www.yagga.net/java/miniinstaller/index.shtml)

Comment: IzPack, Antigen, Launch4J, Antstaller, Packlet are all XML-driven.
Java Service Wrapper and VAInstaller are driven by property files.
Lift Off Java Install and Mini Installer are driven by custom configuration files.
JSmooth looks like it's GUI-driven (no scripting) plus version 0.9.9-7 crashes under Windows7.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as accepted because I can understand how my question could have been misinterpreted. I meant that the installer **scripts** should be written in Java, not the installer generator, but I guess I will open a separate question for this.

Comment: PackR is written in Java. It's possible to give it a JSON file in input but it is optional. You can call its main class in your Java code: http://github.com/libgdx/packr If you look for something that goes further and if your project is under GPL, you can use JNDT: http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2014/11/22/ardor3d-est-mort-vive-jogamps-ardor3d-continuation-ardor3d-is-dead-long-life-to-jogamps-ardor3d-continuation/#jndt

Comment: You can add winrun4j too despite its limitations: http://github.com/poidasmith/winrun4j

Answer (score 5):

[lzPack](http://izpack.org/) is a good one

Comment: My team used this to package up Eclipse.  The feedback was all positive.  No idea if it can auto-download a JRE, though.

Comment: I don't think it can auto-download JRE, as it needs JRE in the first place.

Comment: You didn't specify anything about implementation in your question. You asked for a cross-platform generator and this answer is a cross-platform generator

Comment: My question explicitly states: "meaning workflow and plugins are written in Java"

Comment: We used to bundle a JRE and then run izpack through a exe-converter. It worked. Using IzPack to generate a web Installer is pretty simple. You could run that through an exe-converter an get exactly what you asked for except it uses xml for the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this: [http://bitrock.com](http://bitrock.com/) , they allow you to use it for both open and closed software

Comment: Not free for commercial use and somewhat XML-driven.

Answer (score 0):

Update: For cross-platform builds there is an [IzPack plugin](http://izpack.codehaus.org/izpack-maven-plugin/) for Maven.

---

If you're using Maven 1 or 2 for your builds, there is the NSIS plugin (for Windows only).

- [plugin for Maven 1](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/nsis/)
- [plugin for Maven 2](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/)

Both wrap the NSIS command line installer script compiler to generate a windows installer exe from a setup.nsi script.

Comment: Unfortunately, IzPack is XML-driven. I'm looking for a Java-driven workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list: [Open Source Installers Generators in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators)

Answer (score -1):

[openInstaller](https://openinstaller.dev.java.net/) from the [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) project may be worth looking at as well.