# How to build a stand-alone scala executable

Tags: scala, build, executable

I am trying to create a standalone .exe file (or something equivalent) from a scala project I have started. I need to create this in such a way thet the person using the application has to do the least amount of work possible (double-click an installer or just the .exe file). What are my options?

Comment: They're identical to building a Java application. Depending on your OS and development environment you should be able to Google up a solution.

Comment: Any reason you tagged this Scala and not Java? If you are using Scala, are you using sbt to build your project? If so, have you look at the [plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/plugins.html). There is `sbt-assembly` to create a double-clickable jar, and izpack to create an installer. Also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967549/java-packaging-tools-alternatives-for-jsmooth-launch4j-onejar)

Comment: Java 8 will also make it easier by enabling people to build "native" packages like exe, deb, rpm etc.

Comment: As others have said, its no different to how you would do for Java. I like [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You are trying to build _a stand-alone **scala** executable_ _from a **java** project_ ? Makes no sense for me. I guess you might be looking for a self executable jar.

Comment: Sorry for the mess-up, I meant from a Scala project. I have edited the post.

Comment: "Why do you want to _execute_ a Scala program? Scala is meant to only for proving that your C.S. thesis compiles." -- quote by me ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look one OneJar. There is also a sbt plugin [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [ej-technologies](http://www.ej-technologies.com/index.html) the creators of JProfiler, they have a couple of products that might be useful to you, quoting from their product page:

- **install4j** A cross platform Java installer
  that generates native installers and application launchers for your
  Java applications.
- **exe4j** A Java exe maker that helps you integrate your Java applications into the Windows operating environment.

These are both commercial products and although I haven't used them, I have used JProfiler for many years.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard of this one: [Lauch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html).

According to the site:

> It's possible to wrap applications on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and
>   Solaris

Answer (score 2):

[IzPack](http://software.clapper.org/sbt-plugins/izpack.html) plugin for SBT might be useful.

Even scala itself uses it: [They use IzPack](http://izpack.org/we-love-izpack/)