# NetBeans Platform Single JAR File

Tags: netbeans, jar, netbeans-platform

Is there any way a NetBeans Platform application can be distributed using only a single JAR file; ideally we would like to use a single JAR file for all platforms, but we would be willing to entertain using different JAR files for each of our supported platforms.

I realize I should have been a bit more specific: By distribute I do not mean install.  We would like to be able to run a NetBeans platform application simply by executing a single executable JAR file, with no other files or installation required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the distribution of the application into a single jar could be done using one of the [following installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276091/installer-generator-written-in-java).

There is nothing that stops you using this approach, although it is worth noting that you can generate native installers for most major platforms - Linux, Mac and Windows and an OS-independent ZIP distribution using just the menu options in the NetBeans IDE.