# Standalone JAR packagers

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, jar

I'm having [some trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50104035/intellij-artifact-build-not-running-from-command-line-or-otherwise?noredirect=1#comment87230563_50104035) getting IntelliJ to output my packaged JAR file so I can run it directly from the command line.

Are there any free stand alone packagers which I can use to manually add all my JARs and specify my main class which will properly package the JAR? I'm really only interested in a packager, not an installer with fancy windows etc.

I'm using Ubuntu and developing JavaFX applications.

I did find [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967549/java-packaging-tools-alternatives-for-jsmooth-launch4j-onejar) and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276091/installer-generator-written-in-java/1276408#1276408) links... I'll give [Install Builder](https://installbuilder.bitrock.com/) and [lzPack](http://izpack.org/) a go and hopefully report back with a positive result.

**UPDATE**

Install Builder seems to require a paid license to distribute your packaged jars. Unfortunately izPack does not seem to work when I execute it from the command line using Java 9. Crashes out.

Trying [Oracle's javapackager command tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html) next.

Looks like I need to use [Ant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html) to deploy standalone JavaFX applications.

Comment: If you want to start by `java -jar prog.jar` any zip utility will make the job as long you stay with the standard JAR layout and Manifest to give the main class. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)

Comment: @PeterMmm thank you I didn't know this. I have found the Oracle docs on the standard JAR format here so will take a look at that also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html

Comment: This also seems very thorough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145772/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-javafx-application-create-jar-and-self-contained

Comment: command line: "jar --help" is useful, as is "javapackager --help"

Comment: If you are going to tackle learning Ant from square one, this tutorial is a good place to start. http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html But it could well be that javapackager combined with jlink and knowledge of jar will be sufficient. I'm still learning this stuff myself.